# Should I use a uniform plot style in the charts of the same paper?

Tags: writing-style

I plotted some of my charts with `R`'s `ggplot` package and the other with `Python`'s `seaborn` package so that there are relatively big differences in the plot style of those charts.

I'm familiar with Python but I've done some statistical work in R and then plotted them out with R, while the others are all done by Python. It is a little troublesome for me to replot some of them with another programming language.

So my question is, should I use a uniform plot style in my paper, or if it doesn't matter to use bothe of the ggplot-like and seaborn-like styles in the same paper.

Comment: It should be as uniform as possible. Either adjust your ggplot2 theme or the plotting style in python. You don't need to use the same software for all plots.

Comment: The quickest route to uniformity may be to get your R code to write all the results of your analysis to a file, and then use Python to read this in and generate the plots.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll get rejected based on this but I would recommend to make the as uniform as possible. Play around with the styling and themes to get them more similar, or if possible you can try to use a different visualization package for Python. I've heard [plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is similar to ggplot but I don't have personal experience.